# Mock class method inside controller with MOQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Using the sample code below how could I use MOQ to mock a (referenced dll) class method

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SampleTestMethod()
    {
        var _controller = new MyController();

        var stub = new Mock<class1>();
        stub.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(2);
        //var retval = stub.Object.DoSomething();

        var result = _controller.MyAction() as ViewResult;
        stub.Verify(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.AtLeastOnce(), "Didn't call DoSomething");
    }//end test


//Controller
public class MyController{
 public MyController(){}

 public virtual ActionResult MyAction(){
  var ret = new class1();
  var result = ret.DoSomething(10);

  //rest of code  

  return View();

 }

}

//external class
public class class1
{
        public virtual int DoSomething(int i)
        {
            return 1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to inject an instance of the external class 'class1' into your controller's constructor. Then you can use Moq to mock it and inject in the fake one. Something like this:

```
public class MyController{
    private readonly IClass1 _class1;
    public MyController(IClass1 class1){
        _class1 = class1;
    }
    // Other code uses this private instance
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test(){
    var class1 = new Mock<Class1>();
    var controller = new MyController(class1.Object);
}
```

Comment: I should be said that this method is called "Dependency Injection" and is a pattern most everyone should be familiar with if they intend to pursue test-driven development.